# Parse issue : Expanded from macro 'max'

Tags: xcode, macos, audio, plugins

i'm trying to build an audio plugin using WDL-OL (a way to build various platforms audio plugins with one and only compatible code) on OSX 10.8 (with XCode 4.6.3)

I'm also integrating wxWidgets 3.0.0 because i need a few of its functions.

There are a few errors that i can't explain (and i searched a lot on gg but found nothing)

all the errors point to one part of the code :

```
#ifndef max
#define max(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(y):(x))
#define min(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
#endif
```

with error : "Expected unqualified-id"

http://pastebin.com/1MWeKFkC

thanks for help

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

okay finally i got rid of the errors.

What i did (and i should've done that way earlier instead of wasting 30 hours in searching) is to start from a fresh project and adding the lines little by little.

i found out that i was including a file that should not be included.

and now everything works.

Jeff